# How to auto implement suggestions in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

How can I auto implement suggestions in Android Studio just like Eclipse. Any idea?
In Eclipse we can click on the suggestions so that it will get implemented by Eclipse itself.

Eg. "If a variable accessed from within an inner class it should be declared final" in eclipse if I get this suggestion by the IDE I am able to click and implement that suggestion by IDE itself. No need to do it manually. that's what I need.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Are you asking for the CTRL+SPACE?

Comment: Yeah I got. Thanks. I thought Ctrl+space will jus help to auto complt...But it will list the suggestions also. Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean but there are a few important shortcuts in Android Studio:

- **Generate**:

  - On Mac: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
  - On Windows: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd>

  With this shortcut you can generate a lot of things like constructors, getters and setters, correct `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations, overriding or implementing methods... Overall its very powerful and very useful.
- **Quick Fix**:

  - On Mac: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
  - On Windows: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

  With this shortcut you can fix most common errors and it can do a lot of work for you. You should never underestimate how powerful refactoring and quick fix are in IntelliJ/Android Studio.
- **Code Completion**

  - On Mac: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>
  - On Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

  As the name implies this is your basic code completion. By default it shows you only the most relevant suggestions and/or classes you have used before, by hitting this shortcut twice you can show **all** suggestions.
- **Show Parameters**

  - On Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
  - On Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

  This shows you parameters of the current method and all of its overloads, this is among the most underrated shortcuts in my opinion as it can make your life **a lot** easier.

Comment: Thanks for the second one. Quick Fix. I searched a lot for it