# Shortcut for assigning method parameter to a field in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse when I press <kbd>Ctrl + 1</kbd> on a method parameter it gives me an option to assign that parameter to a field of the same type.

In following example, after pressing <kbd>Ctrl + 1</kbd> Eclipse would suggest assigning `methodParameter` to the `mClassField`.

```
private class Aclass {

    private RandomType mClassField;

    public Aclass(RandomType methodParameter){
    }
}
```

**Is there a shortcut for this in Android Studio, please?**

There is only an option to `Create Field for Parameter 'xxx'` after pressing <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> which is not what I want. I'd like to assign the parameter to an existing field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only works in Android Studio as long as the method parameter and the field have the same (or close enough) names.

In the mentioned example <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> would suggest assigning the parameter to the field only if the name of the field was `mMethodParameter` (or the name of the parameter was `classField`) as shown here:

```
private class Aclass {

    private RandomType mClassField;

    public Aclass(RandomType classField){
    }
}
```

<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> would indeed offer to generate following:

```
private class Aclass {

    private RandomType mClassField;

    public Aclass(RandomType classField){
        mClassField = classField; // generated code
    }
}
```

Eclipse works a bit better in the way that it considers types too (not only names) when giving you this option.

**EDIT:**
Some other useful shortcuts you can use for automatic assignment:

- <kbd>Cmd + Alt + V</kbd> to convert selected expression to a **v**ariable
- <kbd>Cmd + Alt + F</kbd> to convert selected expression to a **f**ield
- <kbd>Cmd + Alt + C</kbd> to convert selected expression to a **c**onstant

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you mean but by searching something related to your question I have found few things that can make your life a lot easier when working in Android Studio. Here are some resources I found useful:

[How can I auto implement suggestions in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403707/how-can-i-auto-implement-suggestions-in-android-studio/25403998#25403998)

[Android Studio shortcuts like Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657025/android-studio-shortcuts-like-eclipse)

**Android Studio Tips and Tricks: Must Read**

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html

**If you really love to implement eclipse shortcuts on Android Studio**

[Android Studio shortcuts like Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657025/android-studio-shortcuts-like-eclipse)