# Android Studio shortcuts like Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and want to know about shortcuts.
In Eclipse we use <kbd>shift-ctrl-O</kbd> for importing. In Android Studio we use
 <kbd>alt-enter</kbd>. My question about importing override methods and unimplemented methods. Is there a shortcut for these in Android Studio?

Comment: Try this. It will help to change ur shortcuts to your favorite IDE http://stackoverflow.com/a/25419358/3020568

Comment: another answer with most votes is the correct answer.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37437234/2826147)

Comment: Just in case if you want to go with existing shortcuts then they are very easy to find - Just press __Ctrl__ + __Shift__ + __A__ search for the action you want to perform.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Yes, the list of keyboard shortcuts for Android Studio is at **https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html**.

Here are a few that I know.

Check :File ->Settings ->Keymap ->
<*Choose Eclipse from Keymaps dropdown*> or

**Add unimplemented methods:**   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

**Override methods:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

**Format code:**  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**Show project:** <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

**Show logcat:** <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>

**Hide project - logcat:** <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>

**Build:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

**Build and Run:**  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

**Expand all:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad +</kbd>

**Collapse all:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad -</kbd>

**Find and replace:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

**Find:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

In case I'm missing any shortcut that you need you can ask here and for more check [implink!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio/25419358#25419358) or  [link!!](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf):)

Comment: [List of shortcuts](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/HTqy5cjD8hj) for Mac and Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33301300/2114308 This is Ctrl + N replace Ctrl + Shift + T in Eclipse ==> Find Class

Answer (score 253):

You can use Eclipse Short-cut key in Android Studio too.

```
File -> Settings -> Keymap -> <Choose Eclipse from Keymaps dropdown>
```

For Mac OS :

```
Android Studio -> Preferences or Properties -> Keymap -> <Choose Eclipse from Keymaps dropdown>
```

Comment: @TomaszGawel corrected answer marking depends on Answer as per the particular question when asked. Question asked in Dec and Answer in next june.. any Idea hw it can help me ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to map all the short cuts from Eclipse, the ones like Cmd+Shift+R to search all classes, Cmd+O to search for methods in a class etc. Do we need to add these manually?

Comment: @FauxPas: Which version Android studio has you working now? Bcz, this shortcut is working with my Android Studio.

Comment: 1.2.1.1 Actually Ctrl+O etc works, I just needed to add Cmd+O manually

Comment: There is option <Eclipse for Mac> too. Had you try that?

Comment: you made my day, sir.

Answer (score 28):

If you use **Android Studio** with **Mac OS X** these are some shortcuts:

**- Compile java sources** <kbd>SHF</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

**- Build the project** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

**- Run the current configuration** <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

**- Run in debugger** <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

**- Open project properties** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>;

**- Open Android Studio preferences** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>,

**- Find any command** <kbd>SHF</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

**- Auto-format code** <kbd>OPT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

**- Delete line** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

**- Duplicate line/selection** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

**- Copy line** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (with nothing selected)

**- Select next occurance(s)** <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

**Scope based selection**

- Select next higher scope **Option**+<kbd>UP</kbd>
- Select next lower scope **Option**+<kbd>DOWN</kbd>

[image]

**Navigating the code**

**- Open class** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

**- Open file** <kbd>SHF</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

**- Navigate back to last position** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

**- Navigate forward to previous position** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

**- Switch to recently used files** <kbd>CRT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

**Intention Actions**

- If/Switch actions **Option**+<kbd>RETURN</kbd>

[image]

**Create method** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

or

[image]

**Loop an array of ints**

[image]

- Generate Logs usin `logd`, `loge`, `logi`, `logt`, `logm` and `logr`

[image]

**- Project quick fix** <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**- Show docs for selected API** <kbd>F1</kbd>

**- Jump to source** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>down-arrow</kbd>

Most of them I found on [this really good article](http://stablekernel.com/blog/level-up-with-android-studio-shortcuts-and-live-templates/) and [Android Studio Tips and Tricks](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html)

Answer (score 23):

Yes you can go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java and make the** following changes:

1.change Insert imports on paste value to **All** in drop down option.

2.markAdd unambigious imports on the fly option as checked.(For Window or linux user)

On a Mac, do the same thing in Android Studio -> Preferences

3.You can also use Eclipse shortcut key in Android Studio just go to in Android Studio

**File -> Settings -> KeyMap -> Keymaps dropdown Option.
Select from them**

Thankyou

Answer (score 19):

**Important Android Studio Shortcuts You Need the Most**

---

> Navigation Shortcuts

- Go to class  :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
- Go to file   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
- Navigate open tabs   :   <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd>; <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Right-Arrow</kbd>
- Lookup recent files  :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- Go to line   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
- Navigate to last edit location   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>
- Go to declaration    :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Go to implementation :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- Go to source :   <kbd>F4</kbd>
- Go to super Class    :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- Show Call hierarchy  :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
- Search in path/project   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

---

> Programming Shortcuts

- Reformat code    :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- Optimize imports :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Code Completion  :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>
- Issue quick fix  :   <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Surround code block  :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- Rename and refactor  :   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
- Line Comment or Uncomment    :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
- Block Comment or Uncomment   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
- Go to previous/next method   :   <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>UP/DOWN</kbd>
- Show parameters for method   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Quick documentation lookup   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

---

> General Shortcuts

- Delete line  :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Safe Delete  :   <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd>
- Close Active Tab :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>
- Build and run    :   <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
- Build    :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>
- All purpose (Meta)Shortcut   :   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: Most helpful answer to eliminate use of mouse

Answer (score 17):

Another option is :

```
View  >  Quick Switch Scheme  >  Keymap  >  Eclipse
```

Answer (score 15):

Android Studio is built on IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, the popular Java IDE by JetBrains. This allows the user to select their own keymap (supporting different IDE shortcuts in your IDE).

You can use "Mac os X, Visual studio, Eclipse, Netbeans etc.. shortcuts in your Android Studio by doing the following:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Keymap` -> choose "`Eclipse`" from dropdown.

**OR** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> -> `keymap` -> choose "`Eclipse`" from dropdown like this.

[image]

Comment: What is the default keymap in Android Studio Mac ? For me "Ctrl+R"(To Run) shortcut are not working. This and some other shortcuts are not working. I'm currently having "Eclipse (Mac OS X)" as keymap. Then I can't switch to next tab in android studio by clicking "Ctrl+right or left arrow key" it takes me to next desktop instead of next tab in Android Studio.. Help me. ?

Comment: Have you tried to use keymap as "Eclipse" instead of "Eclipse(Mac OS X)"

Comment: All I wanna click the run button instead of shortcut keys

Answer (score 5):

You can change your keymap to use eclipse shortcuts. You can see here how to change keymap. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25419358

Answer (score 5):

**View > Quick Switch Scheme > Keymap > Eclipse**
use this option for eclipse keymap or if u want to go with AndroidStudio keymap then follow below link

[Click here for Official Android Studio Keymap Refference guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

you may find default keymap referrence in

**AndroidStudio --> Help-->Default keymap refrence**

Answer (score 5):

These are some of the useful shortcuts for Android studio (**Windows**)

- <kbd>Double Shift</kbd> - Search EveryWhere
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - quick command search
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>N</kbd> - Find Class (capable of finding internall 
  classes aswell)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - Find File
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>  - Find Uses (To get the call hierarchy)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - goto class definition.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftClick</kbd>  - goto to symbol(variable, method, class) definition/definition.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> - Back
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>  - Right
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd>  - Refactor/Rename

Answer (score 3):

## Update

#### From Android Studio v3.0.1:

In Android Studio, by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for MacOS), you will have following choices (including your solution!):

- Constructor
- Getter
- Setter
- Getter and Setter
- equals() and hashCode()
- toString()
- Override Methods...
- Implement Methods...
- Delegate Methods...
- Super Method Call (When inside an *Override Method*)
- Copyright
- App Indexing API Code (Not available inside class extending *Fragment*.)

> Note: *Some methods are auto implemented* but you can select `Override Methods...` option *to implement other unimplemented methods*.

Answer (score 2):

you can not remember all shortcuts :)
android studio(actually intellij)
has a solution

**quick command search : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not eclipse like you can do eclipse shot cuts just do the following

```
File ->Settings ->keymap -> in the drop down "KeyMaps" select  Eclipse ->
Apply ->ok.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Android Studio(IntelliJ IDEA) Search**

[image]

- `All` - Search Everywhere
  Double <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- `Classes` - Find class:
  Mac: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> 
  Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>
- `Files` - Find file:
  Mac: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> 
  Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>
- `Symbols` - Search by symbol name:
  Mac: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> 
  Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>N</kbd>
- `Action` - Find action:
  Mac: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> 
  Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt+enter</kbd> is a 'fast solving problems option'. If you try it over class name after writing 'implements XXXX' it will suggest you to autoimplemnt that methods.

The correct shortcut for 'Organice imports' is <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+O</kbd>

You can find a really good Android Studio/IntellyJ shortcuts cheatsheet here: [IntellyJ shortcut cheatsheet](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

------Hint-----

Give a try to Live Templates in Android Studio (It's like magic). Just press <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a shortcut in Android studio and can't quite remember the command, simply click **Ctrl+Shift+A** to launch the command search. From here, you can search for any shortcut you want.

Merry coding!

Comment: this is best one.

Answer (score 0):

[These are for shortcuts specific to android studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html).And since it is based on IntelliJ Idea studio,[these](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) will work too

answering your specific question,Android Studion is quite logical wrt to shortcuts,for eg for all the situations you asked,try <kbd>alt-insert</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse key mapping inside Android Studio is the better choice. It will easily adapt to existing key structure. But all the new persons are using new shortcut key structures in Android Studio has. So we will learn and follow Android Studio itself contain shortcuts will help easily interact the team mates.

If you use Android Studio in Max OS X mean to follow the below link. It works for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30891985/2219406

Answer (score 0):

in androidstudio 3.0(>=) in menu bar go to help-> keymap Reference
It will give all the shortcuts ..
 [link](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Save all    Control + S Command + S

Synchronize Control + Alt + Y   Command + Option + Y

Maximize/minimize editor    Control + Shift + F12   Control + Command + F12

Add to favorites    Alt + Shift + F Option + Shift + F

Inspect current file with current profile   Alt + Shift + I Option + Shift + I

Quick switch scheme Control + `(backquote) Control +` (backquote)

Open settings dialogue  Control + Alt + S   Command + , (comma)

Open project structure dialog   Control + Alt + Shift + S   Command + ; (semicolon)

Switch between tabs and tool window Control + Tab   Control + Tab

Navigating and searching within Studio

Search everything (including code and menus)    Press Shift twice   Press Shift twice

Find    Control + F Command + F

Find next   F3  Command + G

Find previous   Shift + F3  Command + Shift + G

Replace Control + R Command + R

Find action Control + Shift + A Command + Shift + A

Search by symbol name   Control + Alt + Shift + N   Command + Option + O

Find class  Control + N Command + O

Find file (instead of class)    Control + Shift + N Command + Shift + O

Find in path    Control + Shift + F Command + Shift + F

Open file structure pop-up  Control + F12   Command + F12

Navigate between open editor tabs   Alt + Right/Left Arrow  Control + Right/Left Arrow

Jump to source  F4 / Control + Enter    F4 / Command + Down Arrow

Open current editor tab in new window   Shift + F4  Shift + F4

Recently opened files pop-up    Control + E Command + E

Recently edited files pop-up    Control + Shift + E Command + Shift + E

Go to last edit location    Control + Shift + Backspace Command + Shift + Backspace

Close active editor tab Control + F4    Command + W

Return to editor window from a tool window  Esc Esc

Hide active or last active tool window  Shift + Esc Shift + Esc

Go to line  Control + G Command + L

Open type hierarchy Control + H Control + H

Open method hierarchy   Control + Shift + H Command + Shift + H

Open call hierarchy Control + Alt + H   Control + Option + H

Writing code

Generate code (getters, setters, constructors, hashCode/equals, toString, new file, new 
class)  Alt + Insert    Command + N

Override methods    Control + O Control + O

Implement methods   Control + I Control + I

Surround with (if...else / try...catch / etc.)  Control + Alt + T   Command + Option + T

Delete line at caret    Control + Y Command + Backspace

Collapse/expand current code block  Control + minus/plus    Command + minus/plus
Collapse/expand all code blocks Control + Shift + minus/plus    Command + Shift +

minus/plus

Duplicate current line or selection Control + D Command + D

Basic code completion   Control + Space Control + Space

Smart code completion (filters the list of methods and variables by expected type)
Control + Shift + Space Control + Shift + Space

Complete statement  Control + Shift + Enter Command + Shift + Enter

Quick documentation lookup  Control + Q Control + J

Show parameters for selected method Control + P Command + P

Go to declaration (directly)    Control + B or Control + Click  Command + B or Command + 
Click

Go to implementations   Control + Alt + B   Command + Alt + B

Go to super-method/super-class  Control + U Command + U

Open quick definition lookup    Control + Shift + I Command + Y

Toggle project tool window visibility   Alt + 1 Command + 1

Toggle bookmark F11 F3

Toggle bookmark with mnemonic   Control + F11   Option + F3

Comment/uncomment with line comment Control + / Command + /

Comment/uncomment with block comment    Control + Shift + / Command + Shift + /

Select successively increasing code blocks  Control + W Option + Up

Decrease current selection to previous state    Control + Shift + W Option + Down

Move to code block start    Control + [ Option + Command + [

Move to code block end  Control + ] Option + Command + ]

Select to the code block start  Control + Shift + [ Option + Command + Shift + [

Select to the code block end    Control + Shift + ] Option + Command + Shift + ]

Delete to end of word   Control + Delete    Option + Delete

Delete to start of word Control + Backspace Option + Backspace

Optimize imports    Control + Alt + O   Control + Option + O

Project quick fix (show intention actions and quick fixes)  Alt + Enter Option + Enter

Reformat code   Control + Alt + L   Command + Option + L

Auto-indent lines   Control + Alt + I   Control + Option + I

Indent/unindent lines   Tab/Shift + Tab Tab/Shift + Tab

Smart line join Control + Shift + J Control + Shift + J

Smart line split    Control + Enter Command + Enter

Start new line  Shift + Enter   Shift + Enter

Next/previous highlighted error F2 / Shift + F2 F2 / Shift + F2

Build and run

Build   Control + F9    Command + F9

Build and run   Shift + F10 Control + R

Apply changes (with Instant Run)    Control + F10   Control + Command + R

Debugging

Debug   Shift + F9  Control + D

Step over   F8  F8

Step into   F7  F7

Smart step into Shift + F7  Shift + F7

Step out    Shift + F8  Shift + F8

Run to cursor   Alt + F9    Option + F9

Evaluate expression Alt + F8    Option + F8

Resume program  F9  Command + Option + R

Toggle breakpoint   Control + F8    Command + F8

View breakpoints    Control + Shift + F8    Command + Shift + F8

Refactoring

Copy    F5  F5

Move    F6  F6

Safe delete Alt + Delete    Command + Delete

Rename  Shift + F6  Shift + F6

Change signature    Control + F6    Command + F6

Inline  Control + Alt + N   Command + Option + N

Extract method  Control + Alt + M   Command + Option + M

Extract variable    Control + Alt + V   Command + Option + V

Extract field   Control + Alt + F   Command + Option + F

Extract constant    Control + Alt + C   Command + Option + C

Extract parameter   Control + Alt + P   Command + Option + P

Version control / local history

Commit project to VCS   Control + K Command + K

Update project from VCS Control + T Command + T

View recent changes Alt + Shift + C Option + Shift + C

Open VCS popup  Alt + ` (backquote) Control + V