# How to search method in a file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse there is the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to search a method in a file.
What is shortcut for the same command in Android Studio?

**Found these solution more better:**

http://mussharapp.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut.html

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/four-handy-android-studio-shortcuts-for-eclipse-users/

Comment: hi, use the shortcut `Ctrl + F12`

Comment: If you are used to the Eclipse shortcuts, Android Studio has an option to use Eclipse shortcuts

Comment: on mac use, `CMD`+ `FN` + `F12`

Answer (score 156, accepted):

**Windows :** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

**Mac :** <kbd>cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>F12</kbd>

- And type the name it will show the list.

Comment: in mac El Capitan will just increase the volume.

Comment: You may need to hold down the "fn" key while pressing a function key to actually use the function instead of the quick command. So for example, F8 will pause/play media, while fn+F8 will actually produce F8. In other words, for mac users user command + fn + F12.
Not only does the list appear, but you can start typing to jump straight to a matching method name in the list.

Comment: Note: if you're looking to remap the shortcut, the command name is _File Structure_ and it's under the _Navigate_ menu

Comment: CTRL+FN+F12  // CTRL +F12 opening brightness in windows

Comment: What is the name of this command. I would like to be able to remap it, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 29):

You can search by method name or symbol name using **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>** on Windows & **<kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>** on Mac. This will search throughout the project.

Additionally, you can use **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>** on Windows and **<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>** on Mac to search in the current class.

Check http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html for more shortcuts.

Also, you can edit shortcuts in `Preferences -> Keymap`.

Comment: Shorcut by search by method name or symbol algo woking in linux.

Answer (score 8):

**Press** <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to search symbols on **Mac**.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac use the following key combo inside the open code file: CMD+F12

Answer (score 0):

Find method in current file

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Find Symbols in Project

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

[[Find shortcuts]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63776553/4770877)

Answer (score -1):

**Android Studio 1.4.0 on Mac**

Some one said that `cmd + f12` on Mac would do the job, but it didn't work.  However, press `COMMAND + N` -> `GENERATE` -> click on `Override Method`

**EDIT**

**NOTE:** If `cmd + f12` works for you and some people, fine, very good.  BUT, if it doesn't work for others, like me, then try my solution.  It is a real and working solution.

Comment: cmd + F12 (with fn key pressed) does the job pretty well

Comment: @vabhatia well its not my fault that didn't work for me.  This is a real unfair -1. PLUS, my answer is from OCT 23'15 which mean that if you tried today or a few weeks ago that could have change. PLUS, things doesn't work for everybody this is why if you find another solution then you add it here.  This is why you see many SOLUTIONS for one question.  My SOLUTION is a real and working SOLUTION.  PLUS, I do specified that "IT DIDN'T WORK FOR ME" in other words, I am saying, hey guys if `cmd + F12` doesn't work for you, then try this my solution because at least it do works for me.   Thank You

Comment: @vabhatia In fact, the user found two better solutions.  You see, many solutions for one question.

Comment: PLUS: another comment stated that :** in mac El Capitan will just increase the volume.**

Comment: -1 is not because cmd+F12 didn't work for you. Its solely because cmd+N->Generate->click on override method is not solving the problem being discussed.

Comment: @JMASTERB sound like you're looking for override method shortcut instead.It's the wrong subject but it is cmd+O