# 'Find All' in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, full-text-search

New to Android Studio and I wanted to find all instances of something across all java files. I read that <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> would bring up a 'Search Everywhere' box but it doesn't work. You can see from the image below that the text is in the open class and it says 'Nothing Found'. Am I missing something?

Greg
[image]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

You can also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: That go it. It is "Find in Path..." on the menu. Didn't make the connection. Still not sure what the shift+shift was doing, but I guess it doesn't matter now. Thanks.

Comment: The shift+shift lets you search for files (by their file names) in the project for faster switching between files.

Comment: And also functions/variables declarations

Answer (score 10):

In Android Studio: version-1.3.1 -- for MAC

1. Do the following for finding anything in the project:
   command + shift + F
2. Do the following for finding anything and then Replacing in the project:
   command + shift + R.

[image: Replace dialog]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> is used for searching Classes, Files, Symbols, Actions[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63776553/4770877) but not for searching in source files

To find something in code use

```
//global
Edit -> Find -> Find in Path...
//or
Command + Shift + F

//local
Edit -> Find -> Find...
//or
Command + F
```

Answer (score -2):

For me I just wanted to find lines where a particular word was used:
so for that Shortcut: (Mac: cmnd+F /).

[image]