# Android Studio - Find in Path error

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio 2.2.2 in **Find in Path** I was trying search for the string

> String params[]

so I typed it into the "Text to find:" box and I got the error

*Bad pattern "String params[]"  unclosed character class*

What does this mean and how do I search for my string?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think you have regular expressions on. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBTE5.png). Uncheck that and see if it helps.

Comment: I checked here and yep, that replicates the problem. Turns out this is the actual answer. I'm posting an answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You have 'regular expressions' checked, so you're looking for that pattern.

See

[image: this].

Uncheck that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First the Android Studio nice for search whole project,  As mentioned those question  ['Find All' in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954385/find-all-in-android-studio)
and this
[Search all the occurrences of a string in the entire project in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252180/search-all-the-occurrences-of-a-string-in-the-entire-project-in-android-studio)
if you have the problem with 'Find in Path', you could test another like:

On Windows:
Find : Ctrl + F

Find And Replace In Single Class: Ctrl + R

on Mac:
Find : Command+ F
Find And Replace In Single Class: Command+ R

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the regular expression which you put in "text to find" . the [ and ] are itself used in regex so you have to escape these brackets or in other words tell the finder that it is part of string i want to search.. so

String params\[\] should work and you should get the usages of String params[].

Comment: its double backslash . i dont know why stackoverflow editor convert it to single..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, once that 'find in path' stopped working.
Then I found how to enable it again. You need to reformat the java code
by rightclick on  package node and the same with res node. There is an item within the list telling 'Reformat code'.

Answer (score -2):

try...

String Params = params[90your int]