# Android Studio how to navigate to file in Package Explorer

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

In Eclipse, in the workspace screen, I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +<kbd>W</kbd> -> choose `Package Explorer`, it will navigate to to `File` in Package Explorer.

How to do this in Android Studio? (I set key-map `Eclipse` in Android Studio, the hot-key  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>W</kbd> was not available).

Answer (score 3):

Press **Alt + F1** >> show  a popup >> choose **Project Overview** >> **Enter**

This is popup:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Navigate` menu and use `Selct In...` [Option+Command+w] on Mac

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can move between `project` and `package explorer`  by click  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd>  in `Android Studio` For more shurtcut check [https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657025/android-studio-shortcuts-like-eclipse/27657174#27657174)

and
 [Android Studio shortcuts like Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657025/android-studio-shortcuts-like-eclipse/27657174#27657174)

Comment: It only moves between the workspace and Package Explorer. I want to navigate exactly to package contains the file which is being coded.

Comment: If your package explorer is allready opened in android studio than cursor will directly move to perticular project. Check 1nce again ..

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in the workspace.
Select package explorer window.
*[image: emphasized text]*

Click on the "Scroll from source" icon which is marked as red in the above image.
This will do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `Scroll from source` and marking the icon in the screenshot.