# Is there anything like ctrl + shift + T of eclipse in Android studio to see Open Type Window

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, jar

I just want to check some imported class belongs to which jar , that is it. There is alternative by checking each jar for the same package included in my code but i have lot of jar file included in my project , so i am specifically looking for the shortcut like eclipse

Thanks 
In advance.
Yash.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to open up the class view and there you can see from which jars the classes come from.

When you press it once it shows just for local modules/projects. When you press it twice it includes your libraries and you will see it shows where it comes from to the right

[image: class search intellij].