# How to remember Android Studio keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: command + E shortcuts]

As shown in the picture, use command + E to open recent files window, why not command + R(ecent), or other shortcuts?

How does Android Studio author design keyboard shortcuts? I want to know this to help remember shortcuts. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because they chose to use *command + rEcent*. Presumably *command + R* does something else. We can't help you work on your memory. It might be helpful to make yourself a cheat sheet while you're learning the key assignments.

Comment: "How does Android Studio author design keyboard shortcuts?": this is something only the author can answer.

Comment: Sorry for you don't get the key of this question. The reason why I ask this question is many Android Studio's keyboard shortcuts are Irregular. Unlike command + s means save file as it is known to us all. Fox example, use Command + Option + T to Surround with (if...else / try...catch), what this T means? I don‘t think the author design these shortcuts randomly, that means you can find the rules of the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [android developers guide for android studio keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html) which provides detailed list of the most common keyboard shortcuts for all operating systems.

The key to remembering the shortcuts is to:

1. Find out the action you want to be simplified
2. Find if there is a keyboard shortcut using the **keymap settings**
3. Use it whenever you need to and after several attempts you are good to go

> To open the keymap settings, click **File > Settings > Keymap** (on Mac,
>   File > Properties > Keymap).

You can [refer to this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657025/android-studio-shortcuts-like-eclipse).

Comment: Thank you for you help^_^ I have use some shortcuts, but I find many shortcuts are Irregular, and I want to find the rules of these shortcuts to help memory.

Comment: @Smiles The only rule is that if you find a keyboard letter corresponding to a particular command's first letter, you assign that key to that letter. If more than one command starts with the same letter, then you need to find an alternative key or set of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the **Key Promoter** plugin in Android studio which will tell you the keyboard shortcuts and also help you to remember them by prompting then every time you select any option without using keyboard.